Logarithmic integral - is my reasoning correct?
I have been given this definition for the logarithmic integral:
$$\operatorname {li}(x) = \int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log(t)} \tag{1}$$
for $x \gt 2$.
I am trying to prove that:
$$\operatorname {li}(x) = \frac{x}{\log(x)} + \int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2(t)} + A \tag{2}$$
where $A$ is a constant.
My approach was to integrate $\operatorname {li}(x)$ by parts, first I integrated it by parts, getting:
$$\operatorname {li}(x) = \left(\left.\frac{t}{\log(t)} + \int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2(t)}\right)\right\rvert^x_2 \tag{3}$$
I then substituted $x$ and $2$ for $t$, as I would for evaluating a definite integral:
$$\operatorname {li}(x)= \left(\frac{x}{\log(x)} + \int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2(x)}\right) - \left(\frac{2}{\log(2)} + \int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2(2)}\right) \tag{4}$$
Re-arranging:
$$\operatorname {li}(x) = \frac{x}{\log(x)} + \int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2(x)} - \int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2(2)} + \frac{2}{\log(2)} \tag{5}$$
But, I reasoned that the two middle terms are the same as $\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2(t)}$
Leaving:
$$\operatorname {li}(x) = \frac{x}{\log(x)} + \int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2(t)} + A  \tag{6}$$
where $A = \frac{2}{\log(2)}$
Is this correct? Or have I made an error. I am currently thinking that the move from $(2)$ to $(3)$ is incorrect.
Thanks in advance!

I don't understand step $(4)$, in step $(3)$ you only have to evaluate $\frac t{\log t} \bigg|_2^x$ and not the whole expression

The integral is already evaluated since the bounds are $2$ and $x$

Aaaah thanks - that makes sense! Thanks for helping :D

Wouldn't be easier just derivate?

@jjagmath I am not sure what you mean? Can you elaborate please?

The derivative of $\frac{x}{\log x} + \int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log^2 t}$ is $\frac{1}{\log x} -\frac{x}{x\log^2 x}+ \frac{1}{\log^2 x}=\frac{1}{\log x}$ as is the derivative of $\rm{li}(x)$, so the functions differ by a constant.

Thanks @jjagmath, I had not thought of that - I've made a note in my... notes :D

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're doing, it seems to me you've made a mistake in the evaluation of the integration by parts; in fact:
\begin{align}\operatorname{li}(x)&=\int_2^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{\log t}=\frac t{\log t}\Bigg|_2^x +\int_2^x\frac{1}{\log^2(t)} \mathrm dt=\frac x{\log x} -\frac 2{\log 2}+\int_2^x\frac{1}{\log^2(t)} \mathrm dt\\ &=\frac x{\log x} +\int_2^x\frac{1}{\log^2(t)} \mathrm dt+A .\end{align}
